# Call to undefined method JController::getInstance()

Tags: php, web, joomla

i seem to have tried everything. I am trying to learn how to create a new component and currently my folder structure looks like this (please note that the component does install).

This is a picture of my folder structure:

[image]

Ive closed some of it because i found it irelevant but please if you need to see whats inside of them please let me know.

as i stated above the component does install without problems. however when i try to access it i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in /home/marcrasm/public_html/Joomla/administrator/components/com_helloworld/helloworld.php on line 13
```

Now the file it is refering to is this one:

```
    <?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die ('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("/components/com_helloworld/js/jquery.js");
$doc->addScript("/components/com_helloworld/js/com_helloworld_script.js");
$doc->addStyleSheet("/components/com_helloworld/css/com_helloworld_layout.css");

// gets the instance of the controller
// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by HelloWorld
$controller = JController::getInstance('HelloWorld');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

I know it can be hard to tell but does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please check Joomla version

In 3.X

```
   $controller  = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('HelloWorld');
```

In 2.X

```
   $controller = JController::getInstance('HelloWorld');
```

Comment: lol I had two websites one 2.5 and one 3.0 . So I was working like a week on the 3.0 when I returned to fix something in the 2.5 .. and blah! crash! :P

Answer (score 5):

You don't say what version you are on but you probably want JControllerLegacy for J3 unless you are building with the new MVC. JController does not have a getInstance() Method but JControllerLegacy does see github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/controller

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the `JController` does not have the static method `getInstance()`.

Comment: Yeah i know ;) but according the Joomla docs the exteded class does have that method

Comment: So then could you please add the relevant code from JController to your question?

Comment: erm? from where Jcontroller is a part of the Joomla lib isnt it? like when i import it

Comment: You don't say what version you are on but you probably waht JControllerLegacy for J3 unless you are building with the new MVC. JController does not have a getInstance Method https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/controller/controller.php

Comment: @Elin please make that an answer because that was what fixed it. i had to use JLegacy for all of my view,controller and models