# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla-component, joomla3.3

I am trying to upgrade a component from joomla2.5 to joomla 3
 but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JController::getInstance() in /home/evolve13/public_html/components/components/com_donation/donation.php on line 9

Here is the code of donation.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by Donation
JController::getInstance('Donation');

// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JRequest::getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

Comment: Please try asking your question over at [Joomla StackExchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to undefined method JController::getInstance()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901808/call-to-undefined-method-jcontrollergetinstance)

Answer (score 3):

On Joomla 3X you need to use the legacy controllers... try the following code.
Change `JController::getInstance('Donation');` 
To `JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Donation');`